# MSAL(Azure AD) Android Webview is asking for login credentials

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

After successful login with MSAL(Azure AD). I'm trying to load URL(https://portal.azure.com) in webview. After loading it's asking the credentials again but it should load the URL without asking the credentials. Whenever I'm trying to load the same URL in an external browser, It's not asking any credentials. Same behavior expecting with Webview.

Comment: Hey @kunj, can you check which browser you signed into in each request? It's possible MSAL used a different browser than the one you attempted with Azure portal.

Comment: Also, in MSAL are you using the  `AuthorizationAgent=default`?

Comment: Thanks, @DanielDobalian for your quick response. I'm using Webview(Android View), Webview is a layout where we can display the web content and It's my primary requirement And I'm loading the Azure Portal URL in the same object reference of webview.

Comment: @DanielDobalian Webview User Agent String is --- "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; Pixel XL Build/PPR2.181005.003; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/70.0.3538.80 Mobile Safari/537.36"

Comment: Awesome details, thanks. It's hard to say without diving deeper. Our expectation is, within the same app, the cookies set for the Azure AD account to be accessible by both the app and web apps being launched.  Would you mind [opening an issue](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues) so we can investigate? If possible, grab logs as well as your obsfucated configuration object and include them in the issue. Also, my email is on my stackoverflow profile if you have any other questions about MSAL Android/want to chat.

Comment: I already opened a ticket in [GitHub - #450](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/450). I'll try to do some investigation from my side otherwise I'll ping you

Comment: Perfect, lease do try to capture some logs. We'll have an engineer follow up on the issue.

Comment: @DanielDobalian Finally, I got the solution - We have to use Chrome custom tabs (Android support lib). Chrome custome comes with two main features those are following
1. Occurs in a secure context (the system browser) where the host app cannot inspect contents.
2. Has a shared cookie state, ensuring the user has to sign in only once.
[Reference Link](https://developer.android.com/work/guide#sso)

Comment: Thanks for following up! I added a note to your github issue that I highly recommend taking a look at. I think you're on the right path, but need to refine the logic a bit to handle two cases: 1) MSAL uses the default browser that may not be Chrome and/or 2) The case the device does not have Chrome or it is disabled.

Comment: @KunjGupta. You could add it as an answer to close this thread.